# SQLite database not storing data - Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have implemented a static sort of SQLite Database for my app. The app can only read from the database once it is built. There are no methods for update or delete. I get an exception in LogCat that RestaurantID is not unique. Here is my implementation:

**RLocationDatabase.java**

```
public class RLocationDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "RGeoDbase";

public static final String TABLE_RG = "RGeoDbase";
public static final String R_ID = "RestaurantID";
public static final String R_Name = "Name";
public static final String R_Latitude = "Latitude";
public static final String R_Longitude = "Longitude";

public static final String [] COLUMNS = {R_ID,R_Name,R_Latitude,R_Longitude};


public RLocationDatabase(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase data){

    String CREATE_DB = "CREATE TABLE RGeoDbase ( " + "RestaurantID VARCHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY, " + "Name TEXT, "
                        + "Latitude DECIMAL(10,8), " + "Longitude DECIMAL(11,8) )";

    data.execSQL(CREATE_DB);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase data, int oldV, int newV){

    data.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS RGeoDbase");

    this.onCreate(data);
}

public void insertRecord(String id, String name, double latitude, double longitude){
    SQLiteDatabase dbase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(R_ID, id);
    values.put(R_Name, name);
    values.put(R_Latitude, latitude);
    values.put(R_Longitude, longitude);

    dbase.insert(TABLE_RG, null, values);
}

public Cursor getData(String id){
    SQLiteDatabase dbase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM RGeoDbase WHERE Restaurant_ID="+id+"", null);
    return cursor;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public ArrayList getAllData(){
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    SQLiteDatabase dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM RGeoDbase", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(R_Name)));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    return list;
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private RLocationDatabase myDatabase;
private SQLiteDatabase data;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

myDatabase = new RLocationDatabase(this);
buildDatabase();

ArrayList a = myDatabase.getAllData();
    for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(a.indexOf(i));
}
}

public void buildDatabase(){
        myDatabase.insertRecord("0001", "ABC Fastfoods", 22.28416252, 114.13412900);
    }
    }
```

**LogCat:**

```
06-18 16:37:43.359: E/SQLiteDatabase(25373): Error inserting Name=ABC Fastfoods Latitude=22.28416252 Longitude=114.134129 RestaurantID=0001
06-18 16:37:43.359: E/SQLiteDatabase(25373): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column RestaurantID is not unique (code 19)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table  "RestaurantID" is PRIMARY KEY.There is no need to define value for primary key.

Can you try it like this too :

```
myDatabase.insertRecord("ABC Fastfoods", 22.28416252, 114.13412900);
```

Comment: yes but where do i add my custom primary key in this Format "XXXX"

Comment: if so don't give it as primary key

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList a = myDatabase.getAllData();
for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(a.indexOf(i));
```

`indexOf()` retrieves the index of the specified object. The list does not have an object "0" for example and index -1 is returned.

If you intended to print the object itself, replace

```
a.indexOf(i)
```

with

```
a.get(i)
```

---

To get rid of the "not unique", move the `buildDatabase()` inserts to your database helper `onCreate()` so they are run only once when the database is created.

Comment: Thanks and ignore this. I have updated my question. There is another problem